# How to call instance method in static method

Tags: java, file-io, filereader

So what am I trying to do is to read a `.txt` file and add some record on it using eclipse. I set my resource which I named it as "`fileName`" as private and when I try to call it in main method, there is some error. Here is my code:

```
public class FileController {
    private String fileName;

    public FileController() {
    }

    public FileController(String fileName) {
        fileName = "student.txt";
    }

    public void readLine() {

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);

            // read in the file line by line
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
            }

            fr.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("The file " + fileName + " was not found.");
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println(exception);
        }

    }

    public void writeLine() {

        try {
            // create the PrintWriter
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(bw);

            // write value out to the file
            outFile.println("Coke is nice");
            outFile.println("Diet Coke is even better cos won't put on weight =)");

            // close the file
            outFile.close();

            System.out.println("File created: " + fileName);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println(exception);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileController fs = new FileController();
        fs.readLine();
        fs.writeLine();
    }

}
```

Anybody can give me some clues? These codes keep giving me **NullPointerException error**. I know it's from the `FileController fs = new FileController()` that line, but I do not know how to call instance method in static method.

Comment: I doubt that line is causing the error. Did you look closely at the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks everybody. I fixed it already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
public FileController() {
    fileName = "student.txt";
}

public FileController(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = filename;
}
```

Comment: No no. This is the question :   a private instance variable fileName that stores the file name that the FileController class is going to read from and write to.

(i)            a constructor that initializes the fileName variable in (a).

(ii)          a method readLine that reads a line from the file specified in fileName and returns the line a String.

(iii)         a method writeLine that takes in a String as argument and writes it as a line into the file specified in fileName.

(iv)         a main() method to test the FileController class. The fileName is supposed to be in private

Comment: With the code I provide, your program works. the private is not the problem. If you create a FileController without giving input, the fileName will never be declared and is therefore NULL! You will need your constructors to look like this. And your fileName is still private, you won't be able to edit it after you create a FileController object, because you have neither a getter nor a setter :)

Comment: @Rauryn So you withheld some information and now you post it in a comment to an answer? Can you update the question with this information as well? Nevertheless Xavjer is correct in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
FileController fs = new FileController();
```

should be

```
FileController fs = new FileController("fileName");
```

You should also edit you constructor like this.Since class variable fileName and parameter name in constructor has same name you must have to use "this" keyword for assignment .

```
public FileController(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
```

If the parameter name and the class variable name is different you can do this.

```
public FileController(String name) {
    fileName = name;
}
```

Comment: @Rauryn Can you edit your question and show us what error you are getting?

Comment: This would not work because the Constructor with the input String will just declare the input String and not the private variable. You MUST change the constructors "this.fileName = fileName"

Comment: ... of course you have to, it is the same name. Each argument to the constructor shadows one of the object's fields — inside the constructor fileName is a local copy of the constructor's first argument. To refer to the String field fileName, the constructor must use this.fileName.

Answer (score 2):

I think your constructor should look like this:

```
public FileController(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
```

And the no-arg constructor like this:

```
public FileController() {
    this("student.txt");
}
```

Comment: We must have to use "this" ?

Comment: @AchintyaJha Yes of course. Otherwise you'll be assigning the input parameter to itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the name of the file in the constructor. You should pass a valid file name in there for your logic to work properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your constructor with an argument, or your default constructor should provide a default filename, for instance, in your main:

```
FileController fs = new FileController("somefile.txt")
```

And your constructor needs to be changed to:

```
public FileController(String filename) {
     this.fileName = filename;
}
```

And you could change your default constructor:

```
public FileController() {
     this("someDefaultFile.txt");
}
```

Keep in mind that the later option only makes sense if there is a default file to look for, otherwise you should explicitly pass the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Instance methods can be accessed in static methods using the object reference of the class whose method you are trying to invoke.

Hence using new keyword as you have rightly pointed out will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is by calling new FileController(); you didn't initialized fileName field.
You probably wanted your constructors look like this:

```
    public FileController() {
        this.fileName = "student.txt";
    }

    public FileController(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
```

Then will be calling new FileController(); legit.